# iOS (Swift) - Array of UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have an array `UIButton`s that have a unique `tag` value. When a given button is pressed, I want to load and present a `UIViewController` that is also stored in an array of equal length.

The `UIViewController`s to be presented are subclasses of a subclass of `UIViewController`:

```
class AViewController: UIViewController {}
class BViewController: AViewController {}
class CViewController: AViewController {}
class DViewController: AViewController {}
// ... etc.
```

I've tried storing the array of `AViewController` subclasses using the following:

```
private var array: [AViewController] = [BViewController.self, CViewController.self, DViewController.self]
```

but I get the error **Cannot convert value of type '[BViewController].Type' to specified type '[AViewController]'** for the first element.

I will then present `BViewController` (for instance) using the following:

```
let ViewController = array[button.tag].self
var viewController: AViewController
viewController = ViewController.init()
viewController.transitioningDelegate = self
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
present(viewController, animated: true)
```

Please let me know if this is the incorrect thought process for doing something like this please and thanks for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need instances

```
private var array: [AViewController] = [BViewController(), CViewController(), DViewController()]
```

if the vcs are in IB , then you would do

```
let b = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bID") as! BViewController
let c = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "cID") as! CViewController 
let d = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "dID") as! DViewController
```

Then

```
array = [b,c,d]
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Does this not use a a lot of memory as I have ~10 subclasses of  `AViewController` and each is fairly hefty in size? Thanks again.

Comment: yes, it's a heavy work , you can make a var to keep track of the current index , then load the vc when you need to without making that array or make it an array of storyboard ids

Comment: Thanks. Im writing this programmatically so no storyboards or segues. Is this any more work than using segues? A lot of the `UIButton`s in the view controllers do get initialised until the `viewDidLoad` function is called ...

Comment: you can make a link on the fly such as an Int switch in a function that takes index and return vc like if 1 return BViewController and so on away to make them created when you need to

Answer (score 0):

```
lazy var VCArray :[UIViewController] = {
    return [VCinst(name: "firstVC"),VCinst(name: "secondVC"), VCinst(name: "thirdVC")]
}()

func VCinst(name:String) -> UIViewController {
       return UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(identifier: name)
}
```

Comment: Hope It will solve issue but please add explaination of your code with it so user will get perfect understanding which he/she really wants.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate answer if you want to store array of view controllers as a constant.

```
 struct AppConstant {

       static let yourViewControllers: [AnyClass] = [AViewController.self, 
            BViewController.self, CViewController.self]
}
```